# Linkedin 401 "Unknown authentication scheme" Javascript SDK Auth

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

1 of every 4 times we try to log in via the LinkedIn API we receive the following error.

**It is quite strange because after we refresh the browser and run the auth call again it works. Any ideas?**

```
 {
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Unknown authentication scheme",
  "requestId": "9VFCEA1OLH",
  "status": 401,
  "timestamp": 1523873487174
 }
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPWxp.png)